# Virtual scroll official examples for treepanel generating ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-treetable

I am attempting to get virtual scroll working for the TreeTable, and after following the official examples I am getting `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` when iI expand any of the nodes for my data.

When trying the official demo's with Stackblitz I see the errors are also generated here too, this is happening for both primeng v9 and v10 latest demo examples.

I noticed a GitHub issue has been raised for this also here - https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/8886 but was closed with a workaround referenced to add a `ChangeDetectorRef` and trigger a change detection cycle manually.

I tried this solution with the official stackblitz demo's (https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-treetablescroll-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    this.virtualFiles = Array.from({length: 1000}).map((_,i) => this.createNode(i, 100));
    this.cd.detectChanges();
}, 2000);
```

But it makes no difference, the error is still generated, perhaps I am implementing this incorrectly?

To replicate the issue, you just have to expand one of the nodes displayed in the virtual scroll example.

I am particularly interested in a solution\workaround for primeng 9

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the problem or at least share the steps to reproduce?

Comment: @OwenKelvin - yeah sorry I should have been more specific about replicable steps, I have just added how to at the end of my original question - To replicate the issue, you just have to expand one of the nodes displayed in the virtual scroll example

Answer (score 1):

**Update**:

Some workarounds you can try -

**Option 1**

Change virtualRowHeight to auto - `[virtualRowHeight]="auto"`. But this will really impact the performance of expand/collapse toggle.

**Option 2**

Use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` strategy on your component. But be careful of its side effects (read [this](https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2018/09/27/angular-performances-part-4/) to know how it works). Please see [this stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-treetablescroll-demo-pzphdz?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

**Original answer**:

[This issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/9254) has been fixed in the version `10.0.3`. If you're curious, take a look at [this](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/commit/08ef6912b97b6f2757fc0d18b16d229cfd85fc14) commit which fixes this issue.

Also, checkout [this forked stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-treetablescroll-demo-iwqext?file=package.json). It works without any workaround.

Comment: It does not work, expand one of the nodes in the virtual scroll example and you will get that error

Comment: That's because the installed dependencies on my forked app still shows `10.0.0`, not sure why. Did you try using `10.0.3` version in your app?

Comment: Please checkout again. I forgot to install and click on save - https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-treetablescroll-demo-iwqext?file=package.json

Comment: Ok, I see now yes thanks. I am trying to get this working for a v9 app in particular, cant migrate to 10 just yet because of 'reasons'

Comment: I see.. don't know why your example was using `"primeng": "^10.0.0",`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Akash, issue has been fixed in [later version of the library](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/commit/361cc5ef4d03aaf1db1466047604c1cd79a6a762) and you check the changes attached with [BUG](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/8886) you mentioned and can apply the fix in your code as well:

**app.component.html**

```
...
<p-treeTable #treeTable [value]="virtualFiles" [columns]="cols" [scrollable]="true
  [rows]="100">
  ...
</p-treeTable>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
...
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy { 
    @ViewChild(TreeTable)
    private virtualTable: TreeTable;

    virtualFiles: TreeNode[];
    cols: any[];
  
    private virtualTableSub: Subscription;

    constructor(
        private nodeService: NodeService,
        private primengConfig: PrimeNGConfig,
        private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
    ) { }
    ...
    ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.virtualTable.tableService.uiUpdateSource$.subscribe(() => {
        if (this.virtualTable.virtualScroll) {
          this.cdr.detectChanges();
        }
      })
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
      this.virtualTableSub?.unsubscribe();
    }
    ...
}
```

Take a look at [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-treetablescroll-demo-tah6wi).